# How to prevent edit text from overlapping the view below?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-scrollview

I'm making a diary app. So I made a Linearlayout(I'll call this layout toolbox) of the tools needed to write like this image.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gqtw7.png)

But I type text and edit text gets longer, toolbox overlap the bottom of an edit text. So can't see the text I'm typing.

I've done a lot of googling and I've used a way to add bottom margin to the layout, but it didn't work.

[issue GIF here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWQ09.gif)(Because it is hidden in the toolbox, can see the text I entered before, not the text I typing.)

There was this problem before I added a scroll view. I guess this problem isn't about scroll view.

How to prevent edit text from overlapping the view below?

Here's my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".DiaryActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/save_tap"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/top_line"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    //elements
</RelativeLayout>

<View
    android:id="@+id/top_line"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:background="#D1D1D1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/save_tap" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/top_line">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/toolbox">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top|start"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:hint="@string/hint_diary_title"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="23sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="start|top"
            android:hint="@string/hint_diary_contents"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:textColor="#515151" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/toolbox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:background="@drawable/top_dividing_line"
    android:gravity="center|left"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

    //image buttons
</LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add a linear layout which takes both your Scrollview and your toolbox layout.

Also can you show all of ur xml (including the parent layout?)

Comment: You mean make a new linear layout including Scrollview and toolbox? I tried, but the results didn't change. And I edited it in XML, including the parent layout, so please take a look at it again.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/save_tap"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

</RelativeLayout>

<View
    android:id="@+id/top_line"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:background="#D1D1D1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/save_tap" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/top_line">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/toolbox">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top|start"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="23sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="start|top"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:textColor="#515151" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/toolbox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
    android:gravity="center|left"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I added some colors to display the different layouts
Tell me if this is the behaviour you wants

Comment: I tried, the results didn't change. There was this problem before I added a scroll view. I guess this problem isn't about scroll view.

Comment: can you please add a screenshot, i think i misunderstood your issue, because it's working fine with my layout

Comment: I updated the issue GIF. Please check again. And thank you sooooooo much for keep answering me.

Comment: well i'm sorry but i don't know, my layout is working fine, are u using a fragment? it might come from your manifest too